# Firebase streams fetches data I can't see in the console

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

yeah, I imagine that this sounds pretty strange but maybe some of you have an idea or at least a hint where I could start searching:
I am building an application with flutter and cloud firestore as the server. I connected my app with the collections in the console, I set up the streams - everything has been working fine and the data arrived fastly to be displayed in the way I wanted it to be.
Now, since a few days, I was trying to establish a new function that creates new objects in the firestore. For testing purposes I also deleted a few ones which already existed, which brings the objects I see in the console to 3. However, the stream fetches 11, including the ones I deleted manually and a few which have been created successfully via my function but are not even displayed in the console. And seems like they are appearing out of nowhere. I double-checked all the other collections but there is nowhere to hide for these objects.
And now I don't know what to do. I can't keep on working like this. I will add a bit of code to show I process the data. Maybe someone already experienced this weird behaviour?

```
  Widget _fetchAllGroupsAndBuildList(){
    return StreamBuilder<List<Group>>(
        stream: DatabaseService().groups,
        builder: (context, snapshot){
          if(snapshot.hasData)
          {
            allGroups = snapshot.data;
            return _buildAllGroupsList();
          }
          else if(snapshot.hasError){
            print(snapshot.error);
            return Container(child: Text("Ups, something went wrong."));
          }else{
            return Container(child: Text("Ups, something went wrong."));
          }
        }
    );
  }

  Stream<List<Group>> get groups {
    try {
      return groupCollection.snapshots()
          .map(_groupListFromSnapshot);
    } catch (e) {
      print("Database, getGroups: " + e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  final CollectionReference groupCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(
      'groups');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if anyone stumbles over this:
The error has been due to the versions of the different firebase-components. I updated all the dependencies in the pubspec.yml to the lastest version and
switched the deprecated functions with the latest ones. The code compiled just
fine but the functionality was lost.
I have no idea, why and how, but in the end I downgraded the versions again, used older ones and suddenly everything worked well again.

Hope this keeps anyone from searching a solution for days.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you have [offline persistence](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#access-data-offline) enabled and you're getting the cached version of your data.

It is enabled by default and you can turn it off like this:

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance.settings =
    Settings(persistenceEnabled: false);
```

Note: This must be set before any Firestore interaction is performed.